# change default icon toolbar (Leaflet)

Tags: javascript, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive, leaflet.draw

how can i change default toolbar icon to something else on leaflet..

[image]

picture above show the default view of icon.. i want to customize and change the icon to something else for example the first icon i want to look like as a bridge and second text icon and so on..

i already tried a few ways but did not work.

here my code

```
var electricpole = L.Icon.extend({
        options: {
            shadowUrl: null,
            iconAnchor: new L.Point(12, 12),
            iconSize: new L.Point(30,30),
            iconUrl: 'image/electricpole.png'
        }
    });

L.DrawToolbar.include({
        getModeHandlers: function(map:L.Map) {
            return [
                {
                    enabled: true,
                    handler: new L.Draw.Polyline(map),
                    title: 'Draw Polyline'
                },
                {
                    enabled: true,
                    handler: new L.Draw.Polygon(map),
                    title: 'Draw Polygon'
                },
                {
                    enabled: true,
                    handler: new L.Draw.Rectangle(map),
                    title: 'Draw Rectangle'
                },
                {
                    enabled: true,
                    handler: new L.Draw.Circle(map),
                    title: 'Draw Circle'
                },
                {
                    enabled: true,
                    handler: new L.Draw.Marker(map, {
                      icon: new electricpole,
                      html: '',
                    }),
                    title: 'Place electric pole marker'
                },                                                                      

            ];
        }
    });
```

my code show variable `electricpole` should change icon from   [image] into .. but i try did not work... can somebody help me how to change it.

Comment: I'm also having this same problem. Anyone ever figure this out?