# Add custom icons to Leaflet Draw toolbar

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

**Note:** Simular post to [change default icon toolbar (Leaflet)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44381913/change-default-icon-toolbar-leaflet).

I am trying to add a custom icon for the leaflet Draw toolbar. But i can't seem to figure out how.

[Leaflet draw toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tDUD.png)

As seen on the image, I have two markers. The goal is to change one of the icons in the toolbar. My code is the following:

```
L.DrawToolbar.include({
          getModeHandlers: function (map) {
              return [          
                  {
                      enabled: true,
                      handler: new L.Draw.Polyline(map, { metric: true, repeatMode: true }),
                      title: '...'
                  },
                  {
                      enabled: true,
                      handler: new L.Draw.Polygon(map, { allowIntersection: false, showArea: true, metric: true, repeatMode: false }),
                      title: '...'
                  },
                  {
                      enabled: true,
                      handler: new L.Draw.Marker(map, { icon: new L.Icon.Default() }),
                      title: '...'
                  },
                  {
                      enabled: true,
                      handler: new L.Draw.Marker(map, { icon: new L.Icon.Default() }),
                      title: '...'
                  }
              ];
          }
      });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/Lscupxqp/) with inspect element there is this CSS property :

```
.leaflet-draw-toolbar a {
    background-image: url(images/spritesheet.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Spritesheet is  :

[image: Spritesheet]

You can simply edit `background-image: url();` with the URL of your icon on the `a` element you want (example for polygon one):

```
.leaflet-draw-toolbar .leaflet-draw-draw-polygon {
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='20' height='20'><circle cx='5' cy='5' r='5' /></svg>) no-repeat;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

You can add SVG, image or content.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying! This is really an easy fix if it works. I'll give it a try later.

Have a nice day :)

Comment: I've done it on the demo to try and it work pretty well. No problem and have nice day too !